# openwrt netcat do not work

Tags: openwrt, netcat

I'm having some issue on netcat.
while on my mac the following command works, it doesn't on openwrt

```
echo -n 0 | nc -u -w0 <ip> <port>
```

The ip and port are correct. It doesn't even give an error, but return the usage of netcat itself.

Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The openwrt installed on the arduino doesn't provide all the options as the basic nc: the usage returned was a "can't connect" error in disguise.
Also the direct connection works as usual (without all the arguments).

```
echo 0 | nc <ip> <port>
```